# Install SSL in AWS EC2 documents

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 instance with Apache and Tomcat servers. And I want to add SSL certificates for https access. Since I am new to server technologies, can anybody help me on this? Where do I configure SSL certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Setup a Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) in front of your EC2 instance you can upload ssl certs to these 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_UpdatingLoadBalancerSSL.html

ELB: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/gs-ec2classic.html